# Не получается подключить внешний JavaScript код, если файл js расположен на уровень выше

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Не получается подключить внешний javaScript код через относительный путь, если *.js файл расположен на уровень выше

То есть проблема с подключением следующего кода:

```
<head>
  <script src="/scripts/test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

В то время как код ниже работает без проблем:

```
<head>
  <script src="test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

В то же время подключением *.css никаких проблем нет.

Comment: Посмотрите в инспекторе кода, какая в итоге ссылка получается и от этого отталкивайтесь.

Comment: точку забыли `<script src="./scripts/test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
  <script src="../scripts/test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

Советую почитать, как пользоваться файловой системой через консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваши файлы расположены вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то для подключение нужно использовать эту команду(отличие лишь в "../")

```
<head>
  <script src="../scripts/test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

А если же они расположены так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То подключение делается так(внимание на путь файла)

```
<head>
  <script src="../../scripts/test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

По аналогии можно подключить так скрипт который находится хоть в корне диска. Но если файл в совсем другом месте то можете подключить его прямой ссылкой(пример ссылки по локалки).

```
<script src="file:///C:/312/My%20Promise/script.js"></script>
```